# coloring lines on hover is not working the same for lines with points versus lines only in vega-lite

Tags: linechart, interaction, vega-lite

I am testing interaction with line charts in vega-lite, where I want a specific line to be colored on hover, and the remaining lines to be grey. A [simple version](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoBmOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATZAgBOjQnh4qckAMp5u8ANZhC++DrDcAZmACsYACrIkYAMLcqIToSoxO3FS63oyoyHRqGpCa6HiYOMCQrLpi2Fqp6HyWNrB08LAUkAC+6hCQsMhivkbKeZmGsG2QeACehMh59YxK1E1qUK2mqNysDZHIutU1SRi61m0adb39gxJKAxrLdchK8Nyaw9QbEHUAHl1GcQCqYXiDPcjoi6pQLuFimkGKTwAx+3T6A1MIOC3F06FyRxukB6XXQ1GoumEIOwkDioXGkD+jUBpnsjEcBO2kKgAEdWKEjGkjFRqrUkWcxLDrjc6mclBcWiYwKAeTz6o1msZBh1EqKkUSATjYD1UOxuLk2XLwTtTEogsN4ZBNjdEWKKPDWNTIBjkCjjVVDiAHUA) works fine. However, if I change the spec to add points to the lines, the hover behavior doesn't seem to apply the same way to the points as it does the lines. Here is [the specific example I tested](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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). Here is the specification from this example:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v3.json",
  "description": "Stock prices of 5 Tech Companies over Time.",
  "data": {"url": "data/stocks.csv"},
  "selection": {"pts": {"type": "single", "on": "mouseover"}},
  "mark": {
    "type": "line",
    "point": {
      "filled": true
    }
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"timeUnit": "year", "field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
    "y": {"aggregate":"mean", "field": "price", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {
      "condition": {
        "selection": "pts",
        "field":"symbol",
        "type": "nominal"
      },
      "value": "grey"
    }
  }
}
```

I expected when hovering over a point or a line segment, that all segments and points of the selected line should be colored, all other lines and their points should be grey. What I see is that hovering over points only shows a tooltip, does not actually change the colors. Hovering over the line colors the line, but its points still become grey. Also, right after hovering over a point, if I try to hover over a segment of the corresponding line, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

If you add `"encodings": ["color"]` to your selection definition, then it will apply to all color encodings. Try it here: ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoBmOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATZAgBOjQnh4qckAMp5u8ANZhC++DrDcAZmACsYACrIkYAMLcqIToSoxO3FS63oyoyHRqGpCa6HiYOKAQEJCsumLYWqnofJY2sHTwsBSQGgC+6tmwyGK+RsoFmVmQhrAdGllQeACehMgFkLCMStQtiQPZ7aao3KxNkci6c-OQyErw3JpT1L04ANqQ+2LcmwC6-WC1dQ1QGLrWfQOQw6PjEkpjz2yhG4UzwH22LkYYhamgKeF0rGQ90eEHqSV2+0O03B2QAHjiukY4gBVMJg0xDZDoTaArqQ5qw0wpPAA+7Zb5jUws4LXdD5ZG0yBDAnZdDUai6YQs8ZxUJbT70sSMqD2RiOeWEkacqAAR1YoSMaSMVBqAzRn0u1xFUH2SkObRMYE68ygTRa8Ad4x6GoV4SV41gQ1Q7G4+Vpnw54yUQSmfNN83N2wofMR4wlyGFyLqIFqQA))

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v3.json",
  "description": "Stock prices of 5 Tech Companies over Time.",
  "data": {
    "url": "data/stocks.csv"
  },
  "selection": {
    "pts": {
      "type": "single",
      "on": "mouseover",
      "encodings": ["color"]
    }
  },
  "mark": {
    "type": "line",
    "point": {
      "filled": true
    }
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "timeUnit": "year",
      "field": "date",
      "type": "temporal"
    },
    "y": {
      "aggregate": "mean",
      "field": "price",
      "type": "quantitative"
    },
    "color": {
      "condition": {
        "selection": "pts",
        "field": "symbol",
        "type": "nominal"
      },
      "value": "grey"
    }
  }
}
```